# Reclassify pandas column values

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe is acquired using `pd.read_html()` and yields the following:

```
| country  | values         |
| -------- | -------------- |
| Finland  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1  |
| Norway   | 0 | 5 | 0 | 0  |
| Germany  |        -       |
| ....     | ....           |
```

My goal here is to reclassify the 'values' (string) field according to the following logic. The 'values' field can be seen as 4 numbers ranging from 0 to 150 separated by a `|`. In addition sometimes the field is filled as `-`.

**Logic**:

Get the last number (position wise) which is bigger than 0 and create a new column `level` which represents the index of said number. If the values column doesnt have any numbers write 0 in the level column.

**Example**:

For Finland the last number bigger than 0 would be 1. So the level column value should be 4 (when counting the index from 1).

For Norway the last number bigger than 0 would be 5. So the level column value should be 2.

For Germany the value for the level should be 0 as there is no number in values.

**Workflow**:

I have tried replacing the `|` with `,` ,removing the spaces and converting the result to a list. I am then however stuck since I cannot seem to figure out how to achieve my desired result. I would like to do this entirely inside the data frame and then export to csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) on `values` columns will get you the results you want:

```
def get_level(val):
    l = val.split('|')
    index = 0
    max_ = 0
    try: # for any case the data isn't 4 numbers separated with pipe
        for i in range(len(l)):
            if int(l[i]) > max_:
                max_ = int(l[i])
                index = i+1 # to get index 1-4 instead of 0-3
    except:
        pass
    return index

df['level'] = df['values'].apply(get_level)
```